# Selecting a set of paragraphs with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have an HTML file containing sets of paragraphs, for example:

```
<p>Page 1</p>
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>

<p>Page 2</p>
<p>First line.</p>
<p>Some text here.</p>
<p>Some other text here.</p>

<p>Page 3</p>
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>
```

I need to select all the paragraphs in a page. The content of the first paragraph in page n is always "Page n", but the number of paragraphs in a page is variable, as is the content of the paragraphs following the page number.

How can I select paragraphs between Page n and Page n+1?

So far I could only figure out how to select the first paragraph in a Page, using jQuery:

```
var n = 2;
$("p:contains(Page " + n + ")").next("p").css('background-color', 'red');
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you able to modify the HTML? If so, then make your life easier by wrapping them in `div`s.

Comment: I'm with Sverri here - if you don't know the number of paragraphs one would suggest they come from maybe a CMS system? just wrap it up

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you're stuck with that structure, you're looking for [`nextUntil`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/), which adds following elements up until (and not including) an element matching the selector you pass it:

```
var n = 2;
$("p:contains(Page " + n + ")").nextUntil("p:contains(Page " + (n + 1) + ")").css('background-color', 'red');
```

(Live example below.)

That selects only the paragraphs after the "Page n" paragraph, not the "Page n" paragraph itself. If you also want to include the "Page n" paragraph, use [`addBack`](http://api.jquery.com/addBack) (formerly `andSelf`, but `andSelf` was deprecated in favor of `addBack` in v1.8), like this:

```
var n = 2;
$("p:contains(Page " + n + ")")
    .nextUntil("p:contains(Page " + (n + 1) + ")")
    .addBack()
    .css('background-color', 'red');
```

But if you can modify the structure, I'd probably put the contents of each page in a wrapper element, such as [`section`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-section-element):

```
<section data-page="1">
    <h1>Page 1</h1>
    <p>Paragraph 1</p>
    <p>Paragraph 2</p>
</section>
<section data-page="2">
    <h1>Page 2</h1>
    <p>First line.</p>
    <p>Some text here.</p>
    <p>Some other text here.</p>
</section>
<section data-page="3">
    <h1>Page 3</h1>
    <p>Paragraph 1</p>
    <p>Paragraph 2</p>
</section>
```

Note that I also included a `data-*` attribute identifying the page (also changed the paragraphs containing the page numbers to `h1`; the spec recommends including an `h1`-`h6` element to identify the section). Then it would be simply:

```
$("section[data-page=" + n + "] > p").css(/*...*/);
```

---

Live example using current structure (*without* `addBack`):

```js
var colors = {
  1: "red",
  2: "green",
  3: "blue"
};
var n;
for (n = 1; n <= 3; ++n) {
  $("p:contains(Page " + n + ")").nextUntil("p:contains(Page " + (n + 1) + ")").css('background-color', colors[n]);
}
```

```html
<p>Page 1</p>
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>

<p>Page 2</p>
<p>First line.</p>
<p>Some text here.</p>
<p>Some other text here.</p>

<p>Page 3</p>
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I myself am pretty new to jQuery. Am I right when I assume that `nextUntil()` is a loop like `each()`?

Comment: @RizkyFakkel No, `nextUntil` selects more elements from the DOM, `each` operates on something that has already been selected.

Comment: @jyrkim: You're quite right, it's right there in the docs I linked. (And I didn't know that!) I'll fix it, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you are able to write "Page 1" --- "Page n", then maybe paragraphs should have a class? Am I right to assume they are dynamically added?

Like so:

```
<p class="p1">Page 1</p>
<p class="belongs_p1">Paragraph 1</p>
<p class="belongs_p1">Paragraph 2</p>

<p class="p2">Page 2</p>
<p class="belongs_p2">First line.</p>
<p class="belongs_p2">Some text here.</p>
<p class="belongs_p2">Some other text here.</p>

<p class="p3">Page 3</p>
<p class="belongs_p3">Paragraph 1</p>
<p class="belongs_p3">Paragraph 2</p>
```

That way you can select a paragraph and all paragraphs that belong to it, without the need to calling the content of the paragraph.

Comment: Why not just wrap them in a container?

Comment: I think the question would be more to the OP than me.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you add `id` for each paragraph.

```
<p id="one">Page 1</p>
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>

<p id="two">Page 2</p>
<p>First line.</p>
<p>Some text here.</p>
<p>Some other text here.</p>

<p id="three">Page 3</p>
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>
```

This jquery function selects elements between two tags by id.

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.between = function (elm0, elm1) {
        var index0 = $(this).index(elm0);
        var index1 = $(this).index(elm1);

        if (index0 <= index1)
            return this.slice(index0, index1 + 1);
        else
            return this.slice(index1, index0 + 1);
    }
})(jQuery);
```

You can use it this way

```
$('body').between($('#one'), $('#two')).each(function () {
    // Do what you want.
});
```